# Change styling of selected text when double click

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I want to change styling text that's selected when double click event happen and want to append some element after that selected text. Problem is that the selection of text can be anywhere from the DOM so I can not bind double click event to some particular division.

I've tried to search the selected text and find in which division it's their, but I not able to find, is their any js library to find that word and replace it?

Comment: Then you have a problem, as what you're asking for is going to be rather complicated and it doesn't seem like you've even tried to come up with anything yourself

Comment: I've tried to search the selected text and find in which division it's  their, but I not able to find, is their any js library to find that word and replace it?

Comment: Just getting the selected text is an exercise in itself, then you'd have to wrap the text, possibly accross multiple elements, and applying styles etc. It's going to be complicated, and probably a lot more so than you seem to think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This Code

**JS**

```
$('body').dblclick(function(){
   var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
var selectionContents = range.extractContents();
var div = document.createElement("span");
div.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
div.appendChild(selectionContents);
range.insertNode(div);

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div>
    I want to change styling text that's selected when double click event happen and want to append some element after that selected text. Problem is that the selection of text can be anywhere from the DOM so I can not bind double click event to some particular division.
</div>

<div>
    I want to change styling text that's selected when double click event happen and want to append some element after that selected text. Problem is that the selection of text can be anywhere from the DOM so I can not bind double click event to some particular division.
</div>


<div>
    I want to change styling text that's selected when double click event happen and want to append some element after that selected text. Problem is that the selection of text can be anywhere from the DOM so I can not bind double click event to some particular division.
</div>
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/5wpWb/1/)